# Empty NSString doesn't log

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, init

I want to set auto value for nsstring (like c constructors). Please look below:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[currentNode element] class]);
NSLog(@"%@",[currentNode element]);
NSLog(@"hi!!!!");
```

Console:

```
2012-08-02 14:43:46.958 Test[5070:207] NSCFString
2012-08-02 14:43:46.961 Test[5070:207] hi!!!!
```

Second NSlog is not working because of [currentNode element] is empty! How can i set a value like @"-----" this? I tried to override 'init' but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might help you:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[currentNode element] isEqualToString:@""]?(@"-----"):([currentNode element]));
```

or this

```
NSLog(@"string is : %@", [currentNode element]));
```

Comment: whichever you prefer better. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple macro:

```
#define MIGHT_BE_EMPTY(s) [s length] > 0 ? s : @"-----"

NSLog(@"%@", MIGHT_BE_EMPTY([currentNode element]));
```

Comment: Error message: [NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x20928

Comment: @Econa Yup; it's `length` not `count`.

Comment: @Econa Yeah holex's solution is beautiful.  Good luck.